# How do I make one entire table from Mysql relate to one data variable in another table in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, join, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

Desired outcome:

I want all the variables from ticket_table (ticket_table, ticket_description, type_menu, status_menu, priority_menu) to correlate to one project_name at a time. I would like every time there is a new ticket submitted, all the data variables from ticket_table will be submitted and correlated to a project_name.

project_table

```
---------------------------------------
id |    project_name      | description
---------------------------------------
1  |   Project 1          | This is a description of what project one is
2  |   Project 2          | This is a description of what project two is
3  |   Project 3          | This is a description of what project three is
```

ticket_table

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | ticket_title | ticket_descr | type_menu | priority_menu | status menu
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Name of tik  | Desc of tik  | Issue     | Low           |  Open
2  | Name of tik  | Desc of tik  | Bug       | High          | Resolved
3  | Name of tik  | Desc of tik  | Other     | Med           | In Progress
```

Comment: As is there is no way to relate the tables, you should store project id in ticket

Comment: @P.Salmon should i add project_name to ticket_table or just id to project_id and just add that to ticket table?